# ASP.NET headers collection support multiple with same field-name

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, header, request

IETF RFC allows request to contain multiple headers with same field-name as long as order is preserved and values can be converted to single header with comma-separated list of values

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be
> present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that
> header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)].
> It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one
> "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the
> message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each
> separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same
> field-name are received is therefore significant to the
> interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT
> change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

How does ASP.NET handle the presence of multiple headers with same field-name ?

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[]
```

`Headers[]` is a `System.Collection.Specialized.NameValueCollection` which is a collection of key-value-pairs where the value may actually be a collection of values.

But it's not clear how multiple values are deconstructed from the request headers: is the collection constructed by parsing a single value's comma-delimited list ? or is it deconstructed from the collection of one or more headers of same field-name ?